# How important is a Flip-Y Axis setting?

Tags: 3d

I noticed many open-world games have a setting called Flip Y-Axis. I need to know the significance of adding a Flip Y-Axis setting, that makes it so that if you move the mouse down the camera moves up instead of down, in a 1st-person 3D open-world game.

Comment: why not add the option to keybind your own inputs to begin with? there's literally no reason why every game shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Flight yoke interfaces flip the y axis, why someone would use an inverted y input device for a 1st person game is beyond me.

The flip side argument is why not add it; input is scaled by multiplication anyway and the sign change has no effect on performance.